# Run standalone python script on Apache Zeppelin

Tags: python, scala, apache-zeppelin

I have been using [Apache Zeppelin Notebook](https://zeppelin.apache.org/) for running `Scala` codes. Now a standalone `Python` script needs to be run on the same notebook. Scala codes produce some CSV files in the precedding paragraphs which should be passed as arguments to the Python script. What's the easiset way to run the Python script from another paragraph of the same Zeppelin notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Zeppelin provides several interpreters which can be binded to a respective notebook. Click on the Interpreter Binding option on the top right side of your notebook to see what's supported by your notebook.

[image]

Since it supports the Shell interpreter `%sh`, I simply use this to run the standalone python script with arguments.

```
%sh
python evaluate.py gold.csv pred.csv
```

If you are not sure about the location of the input file and scripts, you can run the Shell command `pwd` in a Zeppelin paragraph to find them.

```
%sh
pwd
```